# Distribution of $10$ different marbles to $6$ different color boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, balls-in-bins

The question is:

> There are $6$ boxes, with each box a different color, and $10$ different marbles. The marbles are scattered randomly in the boxes.
>
> 1. What is the probability that all marbles are in the same box?
> 2. What is the probability that all marbles are in $2$ boxes exactly?
> 3. What is the probability that in the yellow box, red box, green box and blue box will be equal number of marbles in each box?

To solve Q1, I treat that the sample space will be $\binom{10}{6}$, meaning that there are $10$ marbles scattered in $6$ boxes.

I have trouble describing the event space. Should it be $\binom{10}{1}$, picking all $10$ marbles in the same one box? Or $\binom{6}{1}$, picking $1$ box for all the marbles?

About Q2 I have the same situation, about describing the event space. $\binom{10}{2}$, picking marbles, or $\binom{6}{2}$, picking boxes?

Comment: In the first problem, there are six possible favorable outcomes, depending on which box receives all the marbles.  In the second problem, you need to choose which two of the six boxes will receive all the balls and then, for each such choice, eliminate the two cases in which all the balls are placed in the same box.

Comment: Thanks, but in the first case, what is the correct way to write it mathematicaly? 10 on 1 or 6 on 1?

Comment: In the first case, there are $\binom{6}{1} = 6$ favorable cases since we must choose one of the six boxes to receive all the balls.

Comment: Thanks, is my sample space is correct?

Comment: No.  There are six possible ways to place each of the ten marbles, so you should have $6^{10}$ outcomes in your sample space.  Sorry, I did not notice that before.  By the way, this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: For the second problem, you need to multiply the number of ways of selecting two of the six boxes by the number of ways of distributing $10$ balls to the two selected boxes so that neither of those boxes is left empty.

Comment: Thank you, about the Q3 I need to add up all the probabilites?

Comment: Yes, you need to consider the possibilities that each of those four boxes receives no marbles, one marble, or two marbles, with the remaining marbles distributed to the other  two boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are placing balls in boxes.  Therefore, we have to choose which box receives which ball.

The number of elements in our sample space is $6^{10}$ since there are six choices for each of the ten balls.

> There are six boxes, with each box a different color, and $10$ different marbles.  The marbles are scattered randomly in the boxes.  What is the probability that all marbles are in the same box.

There are six favorable cases, depending on which of the six boxes receives all the balls.  Hence,
$$\Pr(\text{all balls are placed in the same box}) = \frac{\binom{6}{1}}{6^{10}} = \frac{6}{6^{10}} = \frac{1}{6^9}$$

> There are six boxes, with each box a different color, and $10$ different marbles.  The marbles are scattered randomly in the boxes.  What is the probability that all marbles are in two boxes exactly.

We have to choose which two boxes will receive the balls, then distribute the balls to the selected boxes so that neither of the selected boxes is empty.  There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to select the two boxes which will receive the balls.  One the boxes have been selected, there are two choices for each ball, so there are $2^{10}$ ways to distribute the balls to those two boxes.  However, two of those $2^{10}$ distributions leave one of those two boxes empty.  Thus, there are $2^{10} - 2$ ways to distribute the balls so that both of those boxes receive at least one ball.  Thus,
$$\Pr(\text{all balls are placed in exactly two boxes}) = \frac{\binom{6}{2}(2^{10} - 2)}{6^{10}}$$